# ElasticSearch too_many_nested_clauses Query contains too many nested clauses; maxClauseCount is set to 1024

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

we are trying to run a very simple Lucene (ver 9.3.0) query using ElasticSearch (ver 8.4.1) in Elastic cloud. Our index mapping has around 800 fields.

```
GET index-name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Abby OR Alta"
    }
  }
}
```

However we are getting back an exception:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "too_many_nested_clauses",
        "reason" : "Query contains too many nested clauses; maxClauseCount is set to 1024"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Now from what I've read in this article [link](https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch/issues/3652) there was a breaking change since Lucene  9 which Elastic 8.4 uses.

The behavior changed dramatically on how this max clause value is counted. From previously being

```
num_terms = max_num_clauses
```

to

```
num_terms = max_num_clauses * num_fields_in_index
```

So in our case it would be 800 * 2 = 1600 > 1024

Now what I don't understand is why such a limitation was introduced and to what value we should actually change this setting ?

A OR B query with 800 fields in the index doesn't strike me as something unusual or being problematic from performance perspective.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're targeting a very specific subset of fields and don't expect `Abby OR Alta` to be potentially present in any of the 800 fields, right?

Comment: Well actually we do. Maybe not all 800 but it could potentially be in a large subset. There are numerous fields in the mapping with things like description, title, country and others. User when he is searching for these values can't be sure in which specific field these values would be and is trying to do a full text search for them

Comment: Agreed, but "know your data" !! You could at least specify them in the query using the `fields` array and even if you come up with a list of 500 fields, it's not only way below 800 but it also allows you to stay below the `max_num_clauses` limit.

Comment: So to sum up :) this setting was introduced to avoid suboptimal clauses. For most business use cases i guess it makes sense. We could just change the limit it to 100.000 and it would work as before but we shouldn't really do that because it's not optimal from performance perspective :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "easy" way out is to [increase the `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` limit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html) in the configuration file to a higher value. It used to be 1024 in ES 7 and now in ES 8 it has been raised to 4096. Just be aware, though, that doing so might harm the performance of your cluster and even bring nodes down depending on your data volume.

Here is some [interesting background information](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/46433) on how that the "ideal" value is calculated based on the hardware configuration as of ES 8.

A better way forward is to "know your data" and identify the fields to be used in your `query_string` query and either specify those fields in the `query_string.fields` array or modify your index settings to specify them as default fields to be searched on when no fields are specified in your `query_string` query:

```
PUT index/_settings
{
   "index.query.default_field": [
      "description",
      "title",
      ...
   ]
}
```

Comment: One thing though is that the value is showing as 1024 not 4096 in the exception and we are on latest version of ES. Upgraded from 8.2 to 8.4 today. But thank you for the response :) it has been super helpful.

Comment: Yes, see the second link I shared which mentions `The maximum number of clauses is computed ergonomically depending on the heap size and the number of processors in a way that it would be possible to create slow queries, but almost impossible to create out-of-memory errors.`

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/81525) is the exact computation being used in 8.2+

Comment: Hmm this is really weird. We are just testing Elastic since we are thinking of using it as our search engine so we were running the free setup of 1GB memory. Now we scaled it a bit to to 2GB and suddenly even a query with a 100 OR values works with out any problems

Comment: Yes, since the [computation depends](https://github.com/romseygeek/elasticsearch/blob/599c2970abbc76bca7054075ca7480dcdd086edb/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchUtils.java#L31) on heap size + search thread pool size (heap * 65K / threadpool_size), if you increase the heap, you increase the maxClauseCount. By that we can deduce, you have the equivalent of about 10 CPUs (based on how the search pool size is [computed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html))